# SQL/HQL Write to table if condition is true

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Is there a way to do something like

```
IF (numRows A > numRows B)
THEN write A into C
```

where A, B, C are tables with same schema?

I am using HiveQL.

Answer (score 0):

Better to calculate counts separately and conditionally run insert overwrite script depending on counts. If you want the same logic in single SQL query, it can be done also, though not so efficiently:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE C
SELECT a.col1, a.col2... --list columns here instead of a.*
  FROM (select a.*, 
               count(*) over() as numRowsA, --counr rows in A
               b.numRowsB 
         from A 
              cross join (select count(*) numRowsB from B) b --count rows in B
       ) a
 WHERE a.numRowsA>a.numRowsB;
```

If `(a.numRowsA>a.numRowsB) <> TRUE` then select will return no rows and table `C` will not be overwritten.